# How to compile React app with webpack where references to SVGs/Images and their output locations follow a certain file structure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Currently working on a project that is built on React with Redux and using webpack (both new to!). I’ve looked around at possible solutions for my SVG issue of not being rendered once compiled but I think the issue is the path that is being compiled isn’t necessarily the path that I use when uploading.

I am using webpack to compile the files. Currently when I compile I get the typical index.html and main.js files in a dist folder.

```
/dist
  index.html
  main.js
/src
  /components
    Categories.js
  /images
    /icons
      ...
      movers.svg
  App.css
  App.js
  index.js
  index.html
```

However, I have svgs that I am trying to get to work. Currently I cannot get them to load. I have tried many different ways (see below for a way I stumbled on stackoverflow) and have not had any success.

In addition, I am uploading to a platform we use at my company that requires the uploaded file structure be like below:

```
/app
  /public
    /images
    /javascripts
    /data
    /stylesheets
    index.html
```

However, I am able to just have my main.js in the javascript folder and not have to put any stylesheets (as the compiled file has all that and works). But I have not been able to get svgs or image asset paths or references to compile in a way that it is either 1. in the main.js file or 2. in a way i can have those assets in the /images folder above and have my main.js file reference that when I upload to the platform

I’ve gotten to a point where my SVGs are also output in my /dist as a number path (like 8997987974974.js) folder, but once moved to the app structure in either the javascript folder (because I assume that because the structure has all three types of index, main, and svgs in one folder) or in images they don’t load.

My React component referencing the svgs:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const svgs = require.context('../images/icons', true, /\.svg$/)

const svgsObj = svgs.keys()
    .reduce((images, key) => {
        images[key] = svgs(key)
        return images
    }, {})

console.log(svgsObj)

const findSvgSrc = (category) => {
    const svgPath = Object.keys(svgsObj).filter((item) => {
        return item.indexOf(category) > -1
    })
    return svgsObj[svgPath]
}

class CategoryList extends Component {


    render() {
        const { categories, setCategory, cName } = this.props
        // console.log(categories)

        return (
            <div className={cName}>
            <div className="category-list">
            <ul>
                {categories.list.map((category) => (
                      <li className="category-list-item" key={category} onClick={() => (setCategory(category.toLowerCase()))}>
                      <img className="category-icon" src={findSvgSrc(category.toLowerCase())}></img>
                      <span className="font-color-white category-name">{category}</span>
                      </li>

                    ))}
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CategoryList;
```

My webpack.config file

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

const htmlWebpackPluginDev = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
});



module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [htmlWebpackPluginDev]
};
```

An example SVG (It works when placed on a page by itself but something could be wrong with it?)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 25 25" style="enable-background:new 0 0 25 25;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#F01446;}
    .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
</style>
<circle class="st0" cx="12.5" cy="12.5" r="12.3"/>
<path class="st1" d="M5.4,16.8c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1c0,0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.2c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0C5.5,16.9,5.4,16.8,5.4,16.8z
     M6.2,16.3c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5C6,16.8,6.2,16.6,6.2,16.3z M5.7,16.6
    c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.3-0.3c0-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.3C5.9,16,6,16.1,6,16.3C6,16.5,5.9,16.6,5.7,16.6z M20.2,16.3c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5
    c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5C20,16.8,20.2,16.6,20.2,16.3z M19.8,16.6c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.3-0.3
    c0-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.3c0.2,0,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.3C20.1,16.5,19.9,16.6,19.8,16.6z M6.1,16.8c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0
    c0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2C6.2,16.7,6.1,16.8,6.1,16.8z M6.3,16.1c0,0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1
    C6.2,16,6.3,16,6.3,16.1z M5,16c0,0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.2c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2C5.1,15.9,5,16,5,16z M23.9,15L23.9,15
    L23.9,15L23.9,15l-0.1-0.1l0,0h-2.5v0l0.1,0.1l0.1,0.2l0.1,0.2l0.1,0.2l0,0.2l0,0.2l0,0.2l0,0.1l0,0.1l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l1.8,0
    l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0-0.2l0-0.1l0-0.1l0-0.1l0-0.1l0-0.1l0-0.1l0-0.2L23.9,15z M3.4,14.7c0.5-0.8,1.4-1.3,2.3-1.3
    c0.9,0,1.8,0.5,2.3,1.3h6.7c0,0,0,0,0,0V7.4c0,0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1H2.3c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1v7.3c0,0,0,0,0,0H3.4z M5.9,15.6
    c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1c0,0,0.1,0,0.2,0C5.8,15.7,5.8,15.7,5.9,15.6z M19.1,16c0,0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.2
    c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2C19.1,15.9,19.1,16,19.1,16z M19.4,16.8c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1c0,0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.2
    c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0C19.5,16.9,19.5,16.8,19.4,16.8z M20.3,16.1c0,0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1
    C20.3,16,20.3,16,20.3,16.1z M19.1,14.4l0.1,0l0.1,0l0.1,0l0.1,0l0.1,0l0.1,0l0.1,0l0.1,0l0.1,0l0.1,0l0.1,0.1l0.1,0.1l0.1,0.1
    l0.1,0.1l0,0l0,0l0,0h2.1V14h0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1-0.1c0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.1h-0.1l0,0l0,0l0,0v-0.1h0.2c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1-0.1
    s0-0.1-0.1-0.1h-0.2l0-0.1l0,0h0.2c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1-0.1c0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.1h-0.2l0-0.1l0,0h0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1-0.1
    c0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.1h-0.1l0-0.1l0-0.1l0-0.1h0.1l0-0.3l0-0.1l0,0l0,0l0-0.1l0,0l0,0l-0.1,0l0-0.1l-0.3-0.1l-0.3-0.1l-0.3-0.1
    l-0.3-0.1l-0.3-0.1L21,11.3l-0.3,0l-0.3,0l-0.3,0l-0.3,0l-0.1,0l-0.1,0l-0.1,0l-0.1,0l0,0v0l0-0.1l-1-1.9l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0
    l0,0l0,0l-0.1,0l-0.5,0l-0.5,0l-0.5,0l-0.5,0l-0.5,0l-0.5,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0.2l0,0.6l0,0.2l0,1l0,1l0,1v1.5h1.4v-0.1h0.3
    v0.1l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0V15h0.7l0,0l0,0.1l0,0.2l0,0.2l0,0.2l0,0.2l0,0.2l0,0.2h0.5l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0-0.1l0-0.1l0-0.1
    l0-0.1l0-0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1l0.1-0.1L19.1,14.4L19.1,14.4z
     M16.2,13.1L16.2,13.1L16.2,13.1L16.2,13.1l-0.5,0l0,0l0,0l0,0v-0.5l0,0l0,0l0,0h0.5l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0.2v0.2L16.2,13.1z M17.9,11.6
    L17.9,11.6L17.9,11.6l-0.1,0l0,0l-0.1-0.1l-0.1,0l-0.1,0l-0.1,0l-0.1,0l-0.1,0l-0.1,0l-1.1-0.1l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0-1.4l0,0l0,0
    l0,0l0,0l0,0l0.6,0l0.6,0l0.6,0l0.1,0l0.1,0l0,0l0,0L17.9,11.6L17.9,11.6z M18,11.6L18,11.6L18,11.6L18,11.6l-0.1-1.8l0,0l0,0l0,0h0
    l0,0l0,0l0,0l0.2,0.4l0.2,0.5l0,0.1l0,0.1l0,0.1l0,0.1v0.4l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0L18,11.6L18,11.6L18,11.6z M19.9,15.6
    c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1c0,0,0.1,0,0.2,0C19.8,15.7,19.9,15.7,19.9,15.6z M19.8,15.3c-0.5,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,1
    c0,0.5,0.4,1,0.9,1c0.5,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-1C20.7,15.8,20.3,15.3,19.8,15.3z M19.8,17.2c-0.5,0-0.8-0.4-0.8-0.9c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.8-0.9
    c0.5,0,0.8,0.4,0.8,0.9C20.6,16.8,20.2,17.2,19.8,17.2z M20.1,16.8c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0c0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2
    C20.2,16.7,20.2,16.8,20.1,16.8z M19.8,14.4c-1,0-1.7,0.8-1.7,1.8c0,1,0.8,1.8,1.7,1.8c1,0,1.7-0.8,1.7-1.8
    C21.5,15.3,20.7,14.4,19.8,14.4z M19.8,17.4c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1.1c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1-1.1c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1.1
    C20.8,16.9,20.3,17.4,19.8,17.4z M5.7,15.3c-0.5,0-0.9,0.4-0.9,1c0,0.5,0.4,1,0.9,1c0.5,0,0.9-0.4,0.9-1C6.6,15.8,6.2,15.3,5.7,15.3
    z M5.7,17.2c-0.5,0-0.8-0.4-0.8-0.9c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.8-0.9c0.5,0,0.8,0.4,0.8,0.9C6.5,16.8,6.2,17.2,5.7,17.2z M5.7,14.4
    c-1,0-1.7,0.8-1.7,1.8c0,1,0.8,1.8,1.7,1.8c1,0,1.7-0.8,1.7-1.8C7.5,15.3,6.7,14.4,5.7,14.4z M5.7,17.4c-0.6,0-1-0.5-1-1.1
    c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1-1.1c0.6,0,1,0.5,1,1.1C6.7,16.9,6.3,17.4,5.7,17.4z M16.5,15h-1.8V15H7.9c-0.4-0.8-1.3-1.3-2.2-1.3
    c-0.9,0-1.7,0.5-2.2,1.3H2.2C2,15,1.9,15.1,2,15.3l0.2,0.4c0.2,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.7s0.6,0,0.6,0c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1
    c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.5-1.4c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.4c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1-0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0
    c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0
    c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0
    c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0
    c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3
    c0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1c0.3,0.4,0.4,0.8,0.4,1.3c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1H17l0-0.3l0-0.2v0l0,0l0-0.2l0,0l0,0l0-0.2l0,0l0,0
    l0-0.2l0,0l0,0l0-0.1h-0.6V15z"/>
</svg>
```

1. How do I compile with SVGs that will allow me to reference in the file structure above? Can I artificially output into an app/public/images/ file so the references make sense when I move them?
2. Is there a reason why my SVGs aren’t working?

Thank you, I will clarify as much as possible if needed!

EDIT: Logging svgObject gives an object with key: value pairs of:

```
./movers.svg:"9fa427b3a238b5ef5d5e350ea4ed4c18.svg"
```

The HTMl reference is:

```
<img class="category-icon" src="9fa427b3a238b5ef5d5e350ea4ed4c18.svg">
```

Dist looks like this:

```
/dist
  9fa427b3a238b5ef5d5e350ea4ed4c18.svg
  index.html
  main.js
```

Again, have to have to have the files be in:

```
 /app
      /public
        /images
          9fa427b3a238b5ef5d5e350ea4ed4c18.svg (maybe? Or does this need to be in javascripts? both don't work...I think the paths are in main.js)
        /javascripts
          main.js
        /data
        /stylesheets
        index.html
```

Comment: When you log svgObj what is it?

Comment: Hey ruby_newbie, svgObj logs an object all my svgs with key:value of
{./movers.svg:"9fa427b3a238b5ef5d5e350ea4ed4c18.svg"}

and in the HTML <img class="category-icon" src="9fa427b3a238b5ef5d5e350ea4ed4c18.svg">